# SQLException: Parâmetro IN ou OUT ausente do índice:: 10

Tags: java, oracle

É primeira vez que estou trabalhando com conexões, estamos fazendo um trabalho para faculdade de uma rede social, agora estamos fazendo o método inserir.

Minha duvida, quando vou executar a classe teste ele me retorna um erro. O que causa este erro?

Obs.: não podemos usar nenhum tipo de *framework*

**ERRO**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Parâmetro IN ou OUT ausente do índice:: 10
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.processCompletedBindRow(OraclePreparedStatement.java:1844)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3608)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3714)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1378)
    at br.com.younews.dao.UsuarioDao.adiciona(UsuarioDao.java:33)
    at br.com.younews.teste.TesteUsuarioDao.main(TesteUsuarioDao.java:20)
```

**Classe Beans**

```
package br.com.younews.beans;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Usuario {
    private String idLogin;
    private String senha;
    private String nome;
    private String sobrenome;
    private String email;
    private String nmUsuario;
    private char sexo;
    private String dataNasc;
    private String fotoPerfil;
    private String localizacao;
    private ArrayList<Usuario> amigos;

    public Usuario() {
        super();
    }

    public Usuario(String idLogin, String senha, String nome, String sobrenome,
            String email, String nmUsuario, char sexo, String dataNasc,
            String fotoPerfil, String localizacao, ArrayList<Usuario> amigos) {
        super();
        this.idLogin = idLogin;
        this.senha = senha;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.sobrenome = sobrenome;
        this.email = email;
        this.nmUsuario = nmUsuario;
        this.sexo = sexo;
        this.dataNasc = dataNasc;
        this.fotoPerfil = fotoPerfil;
        this.localizacao = localizacao;
        this.amigos = amigos;
    }

    public String getIdLogin() {
        return idLogin;
    }
    public void setIdLogin(String idLogin) {
        this.idLogin = idLogin;
    }
    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }
    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public String getSobrenome() {
        return sobrenome;
    }
    public void setSobrenome(String sobrenome) {
        this.sobrenome = sobrenome;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getNmUsuario() {
        return nmUsuario;
    }
    public void setNmUsuario(String nmUsuario) {
        this.nmUsuario = nmUsuario;
    }
    public char getSexo() {
        return sexo;
    }
    public void setSexo(char sexo) {
        this.sexo = sexo;
    }
    public String getDataNasc() {
        return dataNasc;
    }
    public void setDataNasc(String dataNasc) {
        this.dataNasc = dataNasc;
    }
    public String getFotoPerfil() {
        return fotoPerfil;
    }
    public void setFotoPerfil(String fotoPerfil) {
        this.fotoPerfil = fotoPerfil;
    }
    public String getLocalizacao() {
        return localizacao;
    }
    public void setLocalizacao(String localizacao) {
        this.localizacao = localizacao;
    }
    public ArrayList<Usuario> getAmigos() {
        return amigos;
    }
    public void setAmigos(ArrayList<Usuario> amigos) {
        this.amigos = amigos;
    }

}
```

**Classe DAO**

```
package br.com.younews.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import br.com.younews.beans.Usuario;
import br.com.younews.conexao.ConexaoFactory;

public class UsuarioDao {
    private Connection conn;
    private List<Usuario> user = new ArrayList<Usuario>();

    public UsuarioDao() throws Exception {
        this.conn = new ConexaoFactory().getConnection();
    }

    public Usuario adiciona(Usuario usuario) throws SQLException{
        String sql = "INSERT INTO USUARIO (EMAIL_USUARIO, NM_USUARIO, SENHA_USUARIO, TP_SEXO, DT_NASCIMENTO, FOTO_USUARIO, NM_LOCALIZACAO, NM_SOBRENOME, NM_NOME) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        st.setString(1, usuario.getEmail());
        st.setString(2, usuario.getNmUsuario());
        st.setString(3, usuario.getSenha());
        st.setString(4, usuario.getSexo());
        st.setString(5, usuario.getDataNasc());
        st.setString(6, usuario.getFotoPerfil());
        st.setString(7, usuario.getLocalizacao());
        st.setString(8, usuario.getNome());
        st.setString(9, usuario.getSobrenome());
        st.execute();
        st.close();
        return usuario;
    }

    public List<Usuario> listarUsuario() throws Exception{
        List<Usuario> user = new ArrayList<Usuario>();
        PreparedStatement p = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT P.CD_USUARIO FROM USUARIO P LEFT JOIN USUARIO_AMIGO E ON E.USUARIO_CD_USUARIO1 = E.CD_AMIGO");
        ResultSet rs = p.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
            usuario.setIdLogin(rs.getString("CD_USUARIO"));
            usuario.setNmUsuario(rs.getString("NM_USUARIO"));
        }
        rs.close();
        p.close();
        return user;
    }
}
```

**Minha Classe Teste**

```
package br.com.younews.teste;

import br.com.younews.beans.Usuario;
import br.com.younews.dao.UsuarioDao;


public class TesteUsuarioDao {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Usuario user = new Usuario();
        user.setEmail("gui.costa123@hotmail.com");
        user.setNmUsuario("guuilh");
        user.setSenha("123");
        user.setSexo("M");
        user.setDataNasc("03/05/1994");
        user.setFotoPerfil("www.blabla.com");
        user.setLocalizacao("SP");
        user.setNome("Guilherme");
        user.setSobrenome("almeida");
        UsuarioDao userDAO = new UsuarioDao();
        userDAO.adiciona(user);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essa linha

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO USUARIO (EMAIL_USUARIO, NM_USUARIO, SENHA_USUARIO, TP_SEXO, DT_NASCIMENTO, FOTO_USUARIO, NM_LOCALIZACAO, NM_SOBRENOME, NM_NOME) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

Tem um "**?**" a mais.

O `PreparedStatement` está esperando **10** valores e você está passando 9, por isso que o erro diz

> Parâmetro IN ou OUT ausente do índice:: 10

Comment: AAAH cara muito obrigado, mas você sabe como passo um char? agora ele da esse erro na coluna sexo " ORA-12899: valor muito grande para a coluna "SYSTEM"."USUARIO"."TP_SEXO" (real: 2, máximo: 1)" eu to passando um int e no banco está como 1 não entendo

Comment: Faz tempo que não trabalho com Java, mas posso te ajudar. Abra uma nova pergunta que eu vou procurando se há particularidade para passar um `char` pro banco.

Comment: beleza cara, brigado